# Does HighCharts provide support for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, highcharts

> Hi,  I am looking for a Chart library which I can use for all three
> platforms, i.e Android Native, Ios Native and Flutter hybrid development. I want to know if
> Highcharts is providing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some community wrappers for it (i.e. check this thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=41255#p173208), but officially Flutter is not supported yet. This may change in the future.

You can vote for this feature here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13998

Comment: Be aware that the HighChart products used by some packages in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.